# Confusion about how to specify link/button while using @Html.Action helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Like in `@Html.ActionLink`, While using **`@Html.Action()`** for partial views, how do I specify which **button/link** should be clicked to load the corresponding method (say, abc) in a controller (say, xyz) ??

```
@Html.Action("abc","xyz");
```

Comment: `@Html.Action()` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view - ie. it will display the partial view returned by the method when the page is first rendered.

Comment: Thankyou Stephen Muecke. Now I understood.

Answer (score 1):

`Html.Action` method invokes the action method and the result of that will(the generated html markup) will be returned to the view where you included the Html.Action call. This happens when razor execute your main view. There is no way you can associate it to a link and clicking on which will load the Html.Action response.

However you can use jQuery and ajax at client side to achieve this behavior you are after. What you should do is, listen to the `click` event of the link, make an ajax call to your action method and when you get the response of the action method, inject that to the dom as needed.

So in your main view, include a link and a container div where we will show the results from the action method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Load","Details","Customer",null,new{id="myLink"})
<div id="details"></div>
```

Now the javascript to handle the click event and make the ajax call. You may use the jQuery `load()` method.

```
$(function(){

   $("#myLink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#details").load($(this).attr("href"));  
   });

});
```

Assuming you have an action method called `Details` in your `CustomerController` which returns some partial view result.

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
  // to do  : Return something as needed.
  // Ex : return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Shyju. Right now I used @Ajax.ActionLink to load the partial view. The current problem is that the view is getting loaded as a new page and not inside the required div of main page. Any idea on how to rectify it?

Comment: @AJax, That means that you have not included the relevant `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in your view (and as a consequence its making a normal redirect). But better to use the `jQuery.ajax()` methods as Shyju has suggested anyway.